# Whats wrong with my array and array list java for android

Tags: java, android, arrays, class

I dont know whats wrong but every time i want to put the string element in 1. class from my class koca android gives me error.

Plese help me cause i dont know what to do...

Thanks for your ansewers

```
    package com.klemenjezakon.koceSLO;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class KocaInter extends ListActivity {

    int n = 2;
    koca koce[] = new koca[n];
    ArrayList<String> kocee = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        inicjalizacijaKoc();

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, kocee));
    }

    private void inicjalizacijaKoc() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            koce[0].ime = "Nekaj";
            kocee.add(koce[0].ime);
            koce[1].ime="Nekaj";
            kocee.add(koce[1].ime);

    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);

        startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.KocaInter"));
    }

}
```

and clas koca:

```
    package com.klemenjezakon.koceSLO;

public class koca {

    String ime,visina,odprtost,predel,drustvo,oskrbnik,telefon,gms,telefonPD,email,splet,naslov,kategorija,lezisca,jedilnica,cenik,opis,razgled,zanimivejseTure,prehodDoKoc,vzponiNaVrhove;

}
```

Comment: First please put proper title with your question. Second post Logcat entries.

Answer (score 3):

The `koce[]` array is initialized to a *empty* `koca` array *filled with* `null`*s*. You first need to create a `koca` object before you can access or modify its fields.

```
        // Create an instance and store it in the array
        koce[0] = new koca();
        // Retrieve the instance and set a field
        koce[0].ime = "Nekaj";
        // Retrieve the field
        kocee.add(koce[0].ime);
```

Although I have to agree with @KKD: first acquire some debugging information and (attempt to) debug it yourself first. Your code should have thrown a `NullPointerException` where you access `koce[0].ime` since `koce[0]` was still `null`.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't put any value in koce[] array
so koce[0] returns null therefore koce[0].ime rises exception